# How to enable geometric functions for sqlite3 in Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, geospatial, sequelize-typescript, node-sqlite3

I am using Sequelize in a NodeJS app, as ORM.

For the purpose of tests, I have set dialect as 'sqlite' and installed the package [sqlite3](https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3) as recommended by Sequelize documentation. When running the tests I am facing an error of type: `sqlite_error: no such function: st_geomfromtext`.

I am not sure how to add support for geometric functions to `sqlite3` package. I have tried googling on the topic, but I find articles regarding Python and installing some `dll`. Is there a way to do enable the geometric functions for `sqlite3`?

Comment: It's all about adding geometric functions to DB itself. I'm really not sure you can do it for sqlite unlike PostgreSQL or MySQL, for instance.

Comment: Try to look at SpatiaLite, it looks like what you need for Sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Linux` system and installed `sqlite3` on it, then you must need to load spatial library for used spatial function, You can do as follows on `sqlite3` shell.

```
sqlite> SELECT load_extension('mod_spatialite.so');
```

Comment: As in my question, sqlite3 is installed via npm package I assume. But I will give this a go and let you know